# C# reflections - invoking method having parameters of different types

Tags: types, parameters, invoke

How to pass int,string and float to the method called using reflections ? Basically,different types while invoking like this:
 method.Invoke(service, null);
i can pass an object array but how will it know what types i am passing? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method info is coupled to exactly one method. Two different methods can have the same name when their signature (parameters' types) is different.

So if you have an overloaded method, you can get either of them by using

```
public MethodInfo GetMethod(
string name,
Type[] types
)
```

providing the parameters' types in the array.

Comment: Suppose i want to invoke a method like this: getdetails(int id,string name,float avgsal) using reflections. Then what and how should i store it in the object[] parameters array?

Comment: You get your MethodInfo via `var method = type.GetMethod("getdetails", new Type[] {typeof(int), typeof(string), typeof(float)});` and call it via `var result = method.Invoke(myObject, new object[] {myId, myName, myAvgsal});`